# jquery selector variable with event

Tags: jquery

I'm having a trouble with selector variable with jQuery event.

When I store two or three jquery objects into variables, how can I write code in the same event function using them without repeating the same line ? This may sound confusing but have a look at my example and you will get it.

I can write this easily by

```
$("#a, #b").click( function(){ 
 // stuff
} );
```

but when I store them like this:

```
var a = $("#a"), b = $("#b");
```

and wanna assign each of them with the click event.

// This works but too long

```
a.click(function(){});

b.click(function(){});
```

// I want to have something like

```
(a + b).click(function(){});
```

don't know if this is possible in jquery, if so, please help me 
Thanks in advance

This is the jsfiddle link I've tested, http://jsfiddle.net/UmeaW/

Comment: What would be the advantage of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
a.add(b).click(function(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$.each` too:

```
$.each([a, b, c], function () {
    this.click(function () {    
        result.text($(this).text() + " clicked");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wYRGp/)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var c = a.add(b);
c.click(function(){});
```

Comment: `.add` returns a new jQuery object. `c` will still be the same as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

First don't make like $(a, b, c), remember jQuery selector is based in CSS selector
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

make $("#a, #b, #c")

And if you can use the function $.each()

```
$("#a, #b, #c").each(function(){
    var a = $(this);    
    a.click(function(){     
        result.text( a.text() + " clicked");
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xjfsx/